keybindings with xmodmap to perform Mac like shortcuts keys
I have search everywhere, read the document here for xmodmap that came from the post below, and tested this out.  I just can't figure it out and I hoping someone read this with skills to know how to create a couple of key bindings
I come from a Mac, and moved over to a nice Dell laptop using the latest Fedora desktop.  I am very happy with it and want to be productive while coding and using the laptop.
The post below got me as far as being able to bind the right alt+arrows to be able to move from beginning to end of the line.  Nice, but missing some features.
I want to also be able to do right alt+backspace to delete the full line (in mac its cmd+backspace) with post below binds alt+shift+arrows does highlight, but alt+backspace is what I would like
I want to be able to use right alt+shift+brackets (mac works with cmd+shift+brackets to move between tabs in browsers, terminal tabs etc.
I would appreciate any help, thanks.
post solution here

Your example with replacing the Home and End buttons work, because there is a physical representation of what you're trying to do with your shortcut.
Deleting a full line is not something all applications support, and if an application supports it they will have each their own keybinding.
Your last idea of switching tabs however is quite widely supported with Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab, which you could alias to with your method.
